# A distributed transaction is waiting for lock

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I am trying to copy all the values from a column `OLD_COL` into another column `NEW_COL` inside the same table.
To achieve the result I want, I wrote down the following `UPDATE` in Oracle:

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE
   SET NEW_COL = OLD_COL
   WHERE NEW_COL IS NULL;
```

where `MY_TABLE` is a big table composed of 400.000 rows.
When I try to run it, it fails with the error:

> QL Error: ORA-02049: timeout: distributed transaction waiting for lock
>   
> 02049. 00000 -  "timeout: distributed transaction waiting for lock"
>   
> *Cause:    exceeded INIT.ORA distributed_lock_timeout seconds waiting for lock.
>   
> *Action:   treat as a deadlock

I tried so to run the following query for updating one row alone:

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE
   SET NEW_COL = OLD_COL
   WHERE ID = '1'
```

and this works as intended.
 Therefore, why can't I update all the rows in my table? Why is this error showing up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there are too many row in your Table, When you `UPDATE` table will be lock.
oracle default it set to 60 seconds. if your excute time over 60 seconds will be error.

You can try to set up timeout value

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET distributed_lock_timeout=120;
```

or disable it.

```
ALTER SYSTEM DISABLE DISTRIBUTED RECOVERY;
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A84870_01/doc/server.816/a76960/ds_txnma.htm

Note:

- Remember : While running any `ALTER SYSTEM` Command you need to restart the instance.

Comment: So, if I disable it, can I enable it again to the default using `ALTER SYSTEM SET distributed_lock_timeout=60;`, right?

Comment: Yes `ALTER SYSTEM ENABLE DISTRIBUTED RECOVERY;
COMMIT;`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but apparently for running an `ALTER SYSTEM` statement you need to have admin privileges and I've not. However I discovered that another user in my system was updating the same table and therefore it was marked as locked under my point of view. I could then update my big table after his commit without using any `ALTER SYSTEM` command, by simply running the query written above in my question.